# Google Cache showing wrong URL

Tags: url, google-cache

I searched the cache details of the URL `http://property.example.com/pune-properties` but the Google Cache showing details for `property.example.com`. I don't know why it's showing like this. Not only for `http://property.example.com/pune-properties` but also for all the Indian city relates URL's like `http://property.example.com/chennai-properties` , `http://property.example.com/mumbai-properties` , `http://property.example.com/kolkata-properties` etc. Even I don't find these URLs in the Google search result. If I search Chennai properties in Google, I find `property.example.com` and not `http://property.example.com/chennai-properties`. Why its happening like this?

Comment: Might the inner pages have had canonical tags referencing the home page in the past at some point?

Comment: Well, I can see the right version (cache for property.sulekha.com last cached 9th of October).

Comment: Sorry. Some correction in my question. Its not showing www.sulekha.com and its showing property.sulekha.com only. but my question is why its not showing property.sulekha.com/cityname-property ?

Comment: Check the page he posted Łukasz. The cache is the the home page, not the page that is displaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your site can  be accessed both by domain URL and IP address then you will have such issues. That IP corresponds to `sulekha.com` - obvously antoher one of your domains for the same business.

You have to 301 redirect accesses from the wrong IP-based URL to the correct domain-based URL, at the server level. Since you are hosted on an IIS server this is something you may need to take up with your hoster if you don't know where to do it. It may be done through the IIS console or through scripting.

Using fully qualified URLs in navigation would help diminish the incidence of finding more IP-based URLs during navigation.